# Custom Query Parameters without Appending Them to URL

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, yii, url-routing

I have `'urlFormat'=>'path'` and `'showScriptName'=>false` in the `urlManager`.

I have proxies/read as controller/action and article=>some_name as parameters.

Whenever I create a link such as:
$this->createUrl('proxies/read', array('article'=>$name));

The result is an URL of the type:

```
proxies/read?article=socks5_proxy_list
```

I would like to dump the query parameter and reformat the URL to look like this:

```
controller/action/param_name/param_value
```

In this case that would be:

```
proxies/read/article/socks5_proxy_list
```

My current 'rules' look like this:

```
'rules'=>array(
  '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
  '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
  '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/article/<article:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>/article/<article>',
  '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
),
```

But they don't seem to be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Shortcut to make this work:

   ```
   $this->createUrl('proxies/read/article/'.$name);
   ```

   And leave the urlManager rules without your custom rule.
2. Another way:

   ```
   // urlManager
   'rules'=>array(// order of rules is also important
     '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/article/<article:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
     '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
     '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
     '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
   ),
   ```

   In the above array, i just put the new rule in the beginning, to make sure that, that rule is applied whenever such a pattern is encountered. If you have other rules, then just make sure that this rule appears before a more general rule, that can match the pattern. Rule of thumb: more specific rule should appear before general rule.

   create url in view:

   ```
   $this->createUrl('proxies/read', array('article'=>$name));
   ```
3. Incase you don't need any of the default "[user-friendly url](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url#user-friendly-urls)" rules, but only need path format urls, then you only need to specify `'urlFormat'=>'path'` and leave the `'rules'` array empty or omitted all together.

Read the [URL Management guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url) in the definitive guide, if you haven't already.

Comment: try all 3 methods, and pick the one that suits you best

Answer (score 0):

no need for rules..

http://yourhost.com/mycontroller/dosomething/param1/value/param2/value

```
class MyController extends Controller {
   public function actionDosomething($param1, $param2) {
   }
}
```

as for createUrl(). hand it a key=>value array of parameters as a second parameter

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#createUrl-detail

Answer (score 0):

try these set of rules

```
'rules'=>array(
  '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
  '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',  
  '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/*'=>'<controller>/<action>',
),
```